# when return array can be in brackets?

Tags: perl

I have a function, which is not mine. Below is the code

```
my ( $cls_option ) = @_;   
my ( %temp, @temp );    
@temp = split /\,/,$cls_option if ( $cls_option =~ /\,/ ); 
$temp[0] = $cls_option if ( $cls_option !~ /\,/ );    

foreach my $temp (@temp) {  
    $temp{$temp}++;    
}    
@temp = sort keys %temp; 

return[@temp];
```

why return array in brackets?

Comment: `[@temp]` makes shallow copy of @temp and returns array reference. `return \@temp` is the same but without copying. Check http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html if you're not familiar with perl references.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that.

Comment: That's be a good thing to turn in to an actual answer :)

Comment: @Sobrique it's not an answer, it's more a reference to perldoc. :)

Comment: It might interest you to know that that whole quasi argument checking is completely useless. It tried to check if `$cls_option` contains a comma, presumably to check for multiple arguments. But `split` will not return a different answer anyway, so the exercise is completely redundant.

Comment: But it does answer the question as asked, and expands by including a reference source. That's a better answer than I've seen to many questions.

Answer (score 1):

The `[ ... ]` notation creates an array reference, a scalar value. For example:

```
my $aref = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
```

This is similar to doing this:

```
my @array = (1, 2, 3);
my $aref = \@array;
```

So it is more convenient to use sometimes. In this case, it is not a good idea. The better option would be to simply return `\@temp`, since it is a lexical variable and will go out of scope when the subroutine is exited.

You might also be interested in know that this part:

```
@temp = split /\,/,$cls_option if ( $cls_option =~ /\,/ ); 
$temp[0] = $cls_option if ( $cls_option !~ /\,/ );
```

...is completely redundant and can be reduced to

```
@temp = split /,/, $cls_option;
```

Since `split` will never return a different value if the string does not contain the delimiter `,`. Also, `,` does not need to be escaped.

You can also reduce your code further. And I would change the name of your hash to indicate what it does.

```
# dedupe arguments
my ( $cls_option ) = @_;   
my %seen;    

$seen{$_}++ for split /,/, $cls_option;

return [ sort keys %seen ];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return [ @temp ];
```

is basically the same as

```
my @anon = @temp;
return \@anon;
```

There's no need to make that copy here (since `@temp` would otherwise cease to exist), so the author should have used

```
return \@temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that your subroutine would be better (and more Perlishly) written like this

```
sub unique_csv {
    my %uniq = map { $_ => 1 } split /,/, shift;
    [ sort keys %uniq ];
}
```

Comment: That will result in different output if the input is an empty string, but I don't think that's a problem.